# Rails 3: Select box with "add new" function

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a selectbox in a view that is populated with data from another model (called comptes). Here is the code of the view:

```
<%= f.select(:debit, @in.collect {|p| [p.nom, p.numero]} + ['Ajouter compte'], {:include_blank => 'Sur quel compte?'})%>
```

What I'm trying to do is: when the user select the last option ('Ajouter compte'), I want the system to open a new window and go to the new_compte_path.

I think Jquery could help but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done something similar in the past.  You'll need an event handler to detect when that option gets selected; when it is, open up a modal where you can put in the details for the new company.  When the user hits OK, add the company via AJAX, and if the add was successful, add that item to your options list and select it.

To do this, you'll need an ID on your "Add Company" option so jQuery can find it, and then an event handler to deal with it getting selected.  I think I used "option/onclick", but "select/changed" is probably more correct (Might not work in IE, though!  IE often won't send "changed" events until a field loses focus.).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've found a way to open a new modal windows that display the new compte partial. But when I submit it (in the modal view) it goes back to the compte index... Is there a way to go back to the "parent" form after create keeping the data the user would already have inputed before the modal (no refresh page then...)

Comment: @Dannoel - You have to use AJAX rather than regular form submission.  When you submit a form, your browser follows the redirect that your server sends back.  When you use AJAX it doesn't, and you can stay on the same page.